# Determine if a Control was originally a Button or TextBox

Tags: c#, winforms

I have several buttons casted to Conrtol, Something like:

```
Control c1=new Button();
```

Now I need to cast it back to original type of it (Button or TextBox etc),Like so :

```
 var b1=(Button)c1;
```

And in general :

```
var oc=(Original Type Here)c1;
```

The problem is I don't know what the original type is?

EDIT: @Rahul,Thanks For the Help , I'm getting *" ; Expected"*  error in the following code:

```
Control c = new Button();
            var b = (c.GetType())c;
```

How could I fix it?

Comment: http://www.bing.com/search?q=c%23+type+of+control

Comment: @Alex, I know Bing , What I don't know is why I'm being so underestimated on this site..

Comment: I've updated my answer. Check once

Comment: If you have question about your question (aka meta-question) you should ask it on http://meta.stackoverflow.com. Side note: be careful with your edit as you turning the post into [chameleon question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43478/exit-strategies-for-chameleon-questions) which generally not recommended practice.

Answer (score 2):

You can do like below

```
 Control c = new Button();
 c.Text = "hello";
 if (c.GetType() == typeof(Button))
 {
     Button button = c as Button;
     MessageBox.Show(button.Text);
 }
```

Comment: It returns System.Windows.Forms.Control , Please read the question before answering , Thanks,

Comment: @Vahid2016 Have you tried doing it. I'm getting `c1` as `{Name = "Button" FullName = "System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button"}` This is what you are expecting right?

Comment: Yep , I have tried , But mine is Windows Forms not Asp.net

Comment: How do I know about this. You should have added `WinForms` tag for your question.

Comment: I tested with Window forms also. I'm getting c1 as `{Name = "Button" FullName = "System.Windows.Forms.Button"}'

Comment: I haven't added any ASP tags , so that's obviously WinForms , But OK , I'll do that , Thanks ,

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/78400/discussion-between-vahid2016-and-rahul-nikate).

Comment: I've tried way you do,But this needs a lot of if & else .. Anyway , your try worth more than 1 voteup :) , Thanks ,